# Como recuperar Friendly Url en ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Yo tenia problemas con AJAX en mi proyecto (no me lo tomaba directamente), para arreglarlo tuve que modificar esta linea `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;` dentro de mi `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`.

La reemplace por la siguente linea, segun una respuesta de StackOverflow `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;`

---

Ahora el ajax me anda bien, el proyecto me lo toma, pero perdi mis Frendy Users URL's.

O sea que ahora todas mis paginas se volvieron a visualizarse como pagina.**aspx**

Yo no quiero que tengan terminacion `.aspx`

---

Como puedo seguir mantendiendo FrendlyUsers URL's en asp.net, teniendo este RoutConfig:

```
    public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
    }
}
```